# jQuery.ajax gives "TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null" on server but not local

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm having a problem with my jQuery code on http://alpha.spherecat1.com/, but the local copy works fine. As you can see if you visit the site now, the ajax call gives the following error:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null"

I've checked and rechecked and reuploaded everything I can think of. The documentation said to make sure I was sending the right MIME type, which I did to no avail. Here's the offending code:

```js
function changePageAJAX(newPage, method)
{
    if (method != "replace")
    {
        window.location.hash = newPage;
    }
    newPage = newPage.substring(1); // Remove the hash symbol.
    title = "SphereCat1.com | " + fixCase(newPage.replace(/\//g, " > ")); // Set the window title.
    newPage = "ajax/" + newPage + ".html"; // Add path.
    if (newPage == currentPage)
    {
        return; // Don't let them load the current page again.
    }
    $.ajax({ // jQuery makes me feel like a code ninja.
        url: newPage,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data, status, xmlhttp){ renderPage(xmlhttp); },
        error: function(xmlhttp, status, error){ alert(error); renderPage(xmlhttp); }
    });
    document.title = title;
    currentPage = newPage;
}
```

It then goes on to render the page into a div. The pages it's grabbing are visible in the /ajax folder at the previous url. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: which is the value of "newPage" and as an example xml?

Comment: newPage is just the url of the page it should be loading, and the files look like this: http://alpha.spherecat1.com/ajax/home.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is thrown from the ajax call:

```
error: function(xmlhttp, status, error)...
```

Since you are expecting a XML dataType, the call for "ajax/home.html" url will return a mime type "text/html". You might want to omit the dataType totally for jQuery's [intelligent guess](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to kick in. E.g.:

```
$.ajax({ // jQuery makes me feel like a code ninja.
  url: newPage,
  success: function(data, status, xmlhttp){ renderPage(xmlhttp); },
  error: function(xmlhttp, status, error){ alert(error); renderPage(xmlhttp); }
});
```

You also have the following `alert()` in `appendCSS` which I assume is for debugging?:

```
function appendCSS(filename)
{
    alert(filename);
    if (filename != null)
    {
        $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' id='extracss' href='"+filename+"' type='text/css' />");
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured it was something related to the mime type, but I tried changing the type in the server config and using a custom extension, and it still gave the same error. I need to use the xml type so that I can crawl the document tree to retrieve a meta tag. I'll try setting the type again, just to see what happens.

And yes, the alert() is for debugging purposes. :)

Thanks much!

Comment: Alright, after changing the extensions and MIME types again, I got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Turned out to be we had a wrong document.domain setting - one more thing to check!