# jQuery Ajax Get not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

going to http://revyu.com/sparql?query=SELECT+%2A+WHERE+%7B%7D works totally fine by returning an XML file, but as soon as I use jQuery, I'm getting errors:

```
var sparql="SELECT * WHERE {}";
var query = 'http://revyu.com/sparql?query=' + escape(sparql);

$.ajax( {
        dataType: "xml",
         url : query,
         success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
        } 
});
```

> thrownError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null.

Any idea why this is? Thanks a lot!

Comment: seems like a duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189214/jquery-ajax-gives-typeerror-cannot-read-property-documentelement-of-null-on
Thanks Marcel.

Comment: Don't rely on queries sent like this; this can be *very* dangerous, as somebody could send their own queries.

Comment: You can't make XMLHttpRequests from your domain to that domain. Browsers will not allow it.

Comment: Do you have an example page, so we can try it ourselves and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the specified dataType.  See the relevant jquery doc [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests). Try changing the dataType to "text".