# d3 & jquery returning text/plain instead of text/xml

Tags: jquery, d3.js, nginx

I'm trying to implement the [forced edge bundling](https://github.com/upphiminn/d3.ForceBundle) d3 example, exactly as it is on github before modifying. The only changes I've made are putting the files in my nginx server and changing the airlines.xml file location.

So the only code of difference between me and the original html (see github above) is the xml location line:

```
d3.xml("http://localhost/CH_Viz/example/bundling_data/airlines.xml", function(xml) {
    //Transform the XML data into a proper format used by the algorithm
    var raw_edges = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("edge");
```

When I try this, the raw_edges line gives this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null"

But I can access the file by typing in the url being used in my code. It seems to be related to MIME types (similar issue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189214/jquery-ajax-gives-typeerror-cannot-read-property-documentelement-of-null-on)) but I don't understand how to use them. I noticed in the network panel of the javascript console for my attempt airlines.xml is type text/plain, whereas it's application/xml in the working version.

My nginx server has the text/xml mime type, but not an application/xml one. I tried removing text/xml and replacing it with application/xml then restarting nginx but that didn't help :(.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to log xml, as in `console.log(xml)` and inspected this?

Comment: That means it's not finding the url. Try changing the http:// ... to just "./bundling_data/airlines.xml". This assumes your index.html file is in the /example/ folder

Comment: Changing it to "./bundling_data/airline.xml" gives the same error, and I can still see the the file showing in the network section of the javascript console as text/plain. I can preview the file as well, just won't recognise it. I tried the console.log(xml) thing too but didn't get anything more helpful than "xml is not defined". Tried changing the xml bit to the file location too to no avail.